# Display shortcode from text field within a group

Tags: wordpress, advanced-custom-fields

I have an acf text field within a group, holding a shortcode. In my page template I want to be able to output that shortcode. I can do it outside of an acf group with:

```
<?php echo do_shortcode( get_field('shortcode') ); ?>
```

But unsure when it belongs to a group

Comment: are you unsure on how to get fields within a group?

Comment: because that is pretty clear in the docs : https://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/group/

Comment: Have you tried like this?? 

<?php 
$shortcode = get_field('shortcode'); 
echo do_shortcode($shortcode); ?>